# Inconsistency in saving and loading pandas dataframe with lists as values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with one column having lists as values. for example:

```
a = [(1,1,[1,2]),(2,2,[2,3,4])]
In [75]: pd.DataFrame.from_records(a,columns=['a','b','c'],exclude='b')
Out[75]:
   a          c
0  1     [1, 2]
1  2  [2, 3, 4]
```

As you can see, column c actually contains a list. this is verfied by:

```
In [76]: _.c.ix[0]
Out[76]: [1, 2]
```

So here, the dataframe contains true lists, available for later analysis with all the list class functionality. 
But when Im saving the dataframe and then loading it again, the list becomes string:

```
In [72]: _.to_csv(r'D:\test.csv')

In [73]: pd.read_csv(r'D:\test.csv')
Out[73]:
   Unnamed: 0  a          c
0           0  1     [1, 2]
1           1  2  [2, 3, 4]

In [74]: _.c.ix[0]
Out[74]: '[1, 2]'
```

And I lost list functionality. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not a bug. CSV files do not have datatype information. When you load the file, all `read_csv` has to go on is the text. When it sees `[1, 2]` in the file, it does not assume that it should process the contents as a list. (This is proper; a CSV file might contain text in that format that should *not* be a list.)

**Direct Answer**: If you want to turn the column back into a list, do `df['c'] = df['c'].map(ast.literal_eval)`. (You must first `import ast` of course.) You could write this into a "converter" function to do it upon loading -- see the `read_csv` documentation.

**Better Approach**: Save your data as something other than a CSV so that the datatypes can be saved and recovered on loading. The simplest way to do this is to save as a binary file: `df.to_pickle('test.df')`.

**Big Picture**: DataFrames or Series containing lists are unidiomatic: they aren't very convenient to deal with, and they don't make available most of pandas's nice tools for handling data. Think again about whether you really need your data as lists. (Maybe you do, but it should be a last resort.)

Comment: Don't use eval, use `ast.literal_eval` ! (which should work, since I think it's the repr which has been saved).

Comment: I figured something like this had to exist, but I didn't know Python's utility for this best practice. Thanks. BUT: ``literal_eval`` throws ``ValueError: malformed string``. Ideas?

Comment: `literal_eval` all the way, I seem to remember applying this to entire columns in the past. :)