# List gets converted to String while writing to csv file in python

Tags: list, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6

I have written the [this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icrTf.png) in jupyter notebook using python 3.
The second column in my dataFrame is of type list. I am writing it into .csv format using the following code :

`network.to_csv("network.csv", sep='\t')` where "network" is my dataframe.

When I open **"network.csv"** file using : 
`pd.read_csv(...)`. Then the second column is getting converted to type string and I want it to be a list as it was before.  I am new to this. How should I go about it?

**EDIT :**

This the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImEly.png) of the command I used to read the csv file.

Comment: Please tell what you use exactly to read the csv.

Comment: I have edited the question and have posted the screeshot.

Comment: Could you attach a link to an example network.csv

Comment: Please post code as code rather than screenshots.

Comment: Check this link for an example dataset : [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EEq73s_dNQ1joVoL5eu96OO3tBTXqhjLMAXJhM2eItU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: A list can only be a list object inside the python code, the object wont stays the same outside when written to a file.

Comment: @sandeep I doubt there exists any method to read it as list itself. So read the file first later convert them to list using df[col].apply(ast.literal_eval)

Comment: @sandeeppulavarthi if you want to use method mentioned by @Dark please convert your "In Degree" column's values to a valid list of strings. Otherwise it will give malformed string error. You can also do this `df = pd.read_csv('network.csv', sep='\t', names=['Paper(s)', 'In Degree'], converters={'In Degree': ast.literal_eval})`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to store a list in pandas and read it as a list.

A solution I found is to use the json library to convert the string back to a list after importing the dataset:

```
import json
df.list = df.list.apply(lambda x:json.loads(x))
```

Comment: This solution gives the following error on my data: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution which works [here](https://saturncloud.io/blog/pandas-dataframe-stored-list-as-string-how-to-convert-back-to-list/)
it uses `ast` library

```
import ast
df('list').apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

It transforms a string like this: "['01', '02']" into a list ['01', '02']

Comment: the same topic is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982584/inconsistency-in-saving-and-loading-pandas-dataframe-with-lists-as-values